# Flex 4 DropDownList Selected Item

Tags: flex4, drop-down-menu, selected

the standard behaviour of a Flex dropdownlist is to disable the currently selected item from the list. Does anybody know how to override this to allow the user to re-select the selected item (if they so desire)?

NOTE: I don't want there to be a selected item in the list but I still want the selecteditem property to be set in the dropdownlist control, otherwise how will I know what has been selected. This is slighly trickier than it sounds...unless I have missed something...

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but you can listen to close event of the component :

Dispatched when the drop-down list closes for any reason, such when the user: Selects an item in the drop-down list. Clicks outside of the drop-down list. Clicks the anchor button while the drop-down list is displayed.

So, you can access the component and gather the selectedIndex, selectedItem properties.

I guess what I'd like to know is that why you want to "re-select", possible to trigger something again but I'd try close event...